# MySQL query code fix

Tags: mysql

```
$query = "SELECT users.*, ROUND((DEGREES(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS('$lat')) * SIN(RADIANS(users.lat)) + COS(RADIANS('$lat')) * COS(RADIANS(users.lat)) * COS(RADIANS('$lng' - users.lng))))) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.60934 * 1000) AS distance FROM users";
$query .= " ORDER BY distance ASC";
```

Can anyone help me fix this code? Basically users.lat and users.lng are not what I want them to be, I want them to be the values of the current selected row, but the functions probably calculate all rows of those columns together?
For example:

```
SELECT users.*, RADIANS(users.lat) AS v1, RADIANS(44.4121) AS v2 FROM users WHERE id=1
```

v1 and v2 have different values and 44.4121 is what that row has as lat value. How would I change my code to work correctly and just calculate on the current row? I never used complex queries like this before so I'm not sure what would be the best way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: They ARE the values of the current row. What makes you think they're not?

Comment: The only time SQL combines rows is when you use aggregate functions like `SUM()` and `AVG()`.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean, I reproduced it here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e74f/2 The numbers are almost the same, so it looks like there's some rounding error somewhere.

Comment: So looks like I'm not the only one confused :P. Any idea what's going on there?

Comment: Like I said, rounding error. They're the same up to 7 decimal places, which should be good enough for most purposes. Unless you're targeting missiles and need extreme precision, it should be good enough.

Comment: It is pretty bad on short distances like a few meters, so is this a MySQL bug? Nothing I can do about it? Would be good atleast to be able to "error round" them both so I get the exact same result, but I have no idea how I would do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your table creation in sqlfiddle.com to:

```
CREATE TABLE users
    (`lat` float(53))
;

INSERT INTO users
    (`lat`)
VALUES
    (44.4121)
;
```

I'm not sure what level of precision you're looking for but but with the float(53) datatype you should get all readable precision you need

Comment: Thanks! That worked! So basically I need to use double for the columns.